# Does boto3 get_object(...) immediately download the actual file in python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

### Background:

According to the [boto3 `get_object()` documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html?highlight=metadata#S3.Client.get_object), the method `get_object(**kwargs)` has the following response signature:

```
{
    'Body': StreamingBody(),
    'DeleteMarker': True|False,
    'AcceptRanges': 'string',
    'Expiration': 'string',
    'Restore': 'string',
    'LastModified': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
    'ContentLength': 123,
    'ETag': 'string',
    'MissingMeta': 123,
    'VersionId': 'string',
    'CacheControl': 'string',
    'ContentDisposition': 'string',
    'ContentEncoding': 'string',
    'ContentLanguage': 'string',
    'ContentRange': 'string',
    'ContentType': 'string',
    'Expires': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
    'WebsiteRedirectLocation': 'string',
    'ServerSideEncryption': 'AES256'|'aws:kms',
    'Metadata': {
        'string': 'string'
    },
    'SSECustomerAlgorithm': 'string',
    'SSECustomerKeyMD5': 'string',
    'SSEKMSKeyId': 'string',
    'StorageClass': 'STANDARD'|'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY'|'STANDARD_IA'|'ONEZONE_IA'|'INTELLIGENT_TIERING'|'GLACIER'|'DEEP_ARCHIVE',
    'RequestCharged': 'requester',
    'ReplicationStatus': 'COMPLETE'|'PENDING'|'FAILED'|'REPLICA',
    'PartsCount': 123,
    'TagCount': 123,
    'ObjectLockMode': 'GOVERNANCE'|'COMPLIANCE',
    'ObjectLockRetainUntilDate': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
    'ObjectLockLegalHoldStatus': 'ON'|'OFF'
}
```

### Question:

Currently, I just need the data contained in the `Metadata` field. But I want to make sure I am not incurring the unnecessary cost of downloading the contents of `Body`.

Does `boto3` immediately download the contents of `Body` or does it wait until I call `response["Body"].read()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the object's metadata, use [`head_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html?highlight=metadata#S3.Client.head_object):

> The HEAD operation retrieves metadata from an object without returning the object itself. This operation is useful if you're only interested in an object's metadata. To use HEAD, you must have READ access to the object.